# Неверная кодировка при рассылке почты

Tags: email, php

Вот программа, которая отсылает почту моим пользователям:

```
if (mail( "mail@mail.ru", "Заголовок",
   "Текст сообщения",
   "webmaster@site.ru")) {
   echo "Сообщение отправлено"; 
 } else {
   echo "Какая-то ошибка произошла"; 
 }
```

Всё отправляется нормально, но есть проблема: "Текст" сообщения доходит в неверной кодировке. Как мне настроить правильную кодировку?

Comment: Ребят, как можно это сделать на php?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, вы не указываете в хиадере письма какую именно кодировку вы используете!

И что за 4й ("webmaster@site.ru") параметр у вас ?

```
if (mail( "mail@mail.ru", "Заголовок",
   "Текст сообщения",
   "From: webmaster@site.ru\r\nMime: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n")) { // или другая кодировка, нужно указывать ту кодировку, в которой у вас текст!
   echo "Сообщение отправлено"; 
 } else {
   echo "Какая-то ошибка произошла"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Каждый программный язык умеет с кодировками работать, попробуйте вручную их приводить к общей кодировке. Например, вот так я у себя при отправлении мыла насильно всё в UTF-8 перевожу (python):

```
def mail(to, subject, text_mail, html_text_mail):
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
text = text_mail.encode('utf-8') #вот тут приведение к общему
```

Comment: Вот применительно к твоему пояснению:
**Работа внутри скрипта**
http://itdumka.com.ua/index.php?cmd=shownode&node=23
**Работа с локалями**
http://anton-pribora.ru/articles/php/locales/